# How can I create a magic system that works like the one in The Black Company novels?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, magic, homebrew

I'm building a D&D campaign modeled after the *Black Company* books by Glen Cook. I especially like the system of magic used in his books. What guidelines should I follow when creating a magic system of my own to emulate how magic works in the books?

Comment: Which edition are you using?

Comment: @Nemenia Only those familiar with the Black Company series should submit an answer, so more Black Company magic system information is unnecessary. Further, only those who've attempted to use a Black Company magic system (whether published or homebrew) in an actual *Dungeons and Dragons* campaign should submit an answer.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Comment: I've removed the request for a recommendation to suit the desired setting, since that would make sure the question remains closed, since recommendation requests are off topic. (That said, answers can make the case that the easy solution is use X product instead of homebrewing, as usual! Once reopened, of course.) This still needs to be clarified to say *which* game called “D&D” is being played, though.

Comment: Which D&D, and also please unpack how you perceive magic working in the books, what the important part of that is to you (even a published Black Company game might or might not tick what you're looking for, without more specifics).